# What do the different Initializations of Eigen::RowVectorXf do?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

I am reading through some docs, and found two different initializations and usages of `new` with `Eigen::RowVectorXf`. I could not find what the difference was through the documentation, or even that this was a possibility, and was hoping for some clarifications.

Here is the first version:

```
std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf*> V;
std::vector<float> data = {0,1,2,3,4};


V.push_back(new Eigen::RowVectorXf(5));

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
     V[0]->coeffRef(1, i) = data[i];
```

Here is the second version:

```
std::vector<Eigen::RowVectorXf*> V;
std::vector<float> data = {0,1,2,3,4};


V.push_back(new Eigen::RowVectorXf(1, 5));

for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
     V[0]->coeffRef(i) = data[i];
```

I could not find any reference to this in the documentation, and I don't believe that they should be different--is this just a deprecated access feature? If someone could give me an overview of what is meant to be happening in both cases mathematically, and let me know if both are just creating a 1D vector with 5 columns, and filling it, I would be really grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Eigen::RowVectorXf(5)` and `Eigen::RowVectorXf(1, 5)` both declare a 1x5 row vector.

Neither constructor is deprecated. To clarify, `RowVectorXf` is just a typedef for `Matrix<float, 1, Dynamic>`, that is, a float-valued matrix with 1 row. As listed in [the Eigen::Matrix documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html#a8f7eef9d36f1057338309afb339c1661), Matrix (and hence also RowVectorXf) has multiple constructors:

- The `Matrix(Index dim)` constructor makes a row or column vector of size `dim`. It is a compile error to call this constructor for a Matrix type that is not known at compile time to have one row or one column.
- The `Matrix(Index rows, Index cols)` constructor makes a matrix of size `rows` by `cols`, and is valid for any Matrix type, including RowVectorXf. As you'd expect, there is an assertion at run time that `rows` is 1 if calling this form of constructor for RowVectorXf.

Yes, the `Matrix(Index dim)` constructor is more useful for RowVectorXf. But it can be handy in generic code that the two-arg constructor may always be used.

Comment: Thank you very much--I thought as much, but its good to hear some confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

Based on what i see in `Martix.h`, `RowVectorXf` is an alias for matrix

`using RowVector##SizeSuffix = Matrix<Type, 1, Size>;`

Where `Type` is `float` (f sufix) and `Size` on 2nd dimension is `Dynamic`.

In both cases you're creating the same thing. Because this Vector is just an alias for Matrix with 1 Row, it's legal to use 2 arg constructor that you'd expect a matrix to have. I believe if you passed anything other than 1 as first arg, you'd get a runtime error (Matrix constructor calls `Base::_check_template_params();`, didn't dig into this one, but it seems to be a runtime parameter validator).

To sum up: both cases seem to do the same thing, but I've based by analysis on source code - I didn't have great experience with Eigen documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much--I thought as much, but its good to hear some confirmation!